# Make available a physical disk to existing Windows VM

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

Problem: I have a new SATA drive I wish to sysprep with a Windows installation. I only have Windows virtualised on my PC.
My Solution: Attach (passthrough) the entire drive to the Windows VM and sysprep as normal.

This is my VGA/Passthrough script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#1st PART
configfile=/etc/vfio-pci.cfg

vfiobind() {
dev="$1"
vendor=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/vendor)
device=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/device)
if [ -e /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver ]; then
echo $dev > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver/unbind
fi
echo $vendor $device > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

}

modprobe vfio-pci

cat $configfile | while read line;do
echo $line | grep ^# >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue
vfiobind $line
done

#2nd PART
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off
/usr/bin/synergys --config /home/%username%/.synergy.conf

export QEMU_ALSA_DAC_BUFFER_SIZE=512 QEMU_ALSA_DAC_PERIOD_SIZE=170 QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
-enable-kvm \
-M q35 \
-m 8192 \
-cpu host,kvm=off,migratable=off,+invtsc,enforce \
-smp 4,sockets=1,cores=4,threads=1 \
-bios /usr/share/seabios/bios.bin -vga none \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=06:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=06:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 \
-soundhw all \
-drive if=none,file=/media/VM/windows1.img,id=disk,format=raw -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=disk \
-net tap,vlan=0 \

-boot menu=on

sudo killall synergys
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --auto
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --right-of HDMI-0

exit 0
```

Question 1): I want to make /dev/sdc available to the VM. What -option format will achieve this. (To reiterate the new disk, sdc, has **no** content, partition or formatting at this point.)

Question 2): Am I making life stupidly difficult for myself and is there is much simpler solution.

Question 3) I do know that this can be achieved by using .xml script that virt-manager uses, but as you see I am not using virt-manager to launch the VM (because of the VGA Pasthrough), would it be possible to convert/import this startup script into the virt-manager .xml format and then add something like:

```
<disk type="block" device="disk">
    <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" />
    <source dev="/dev/sda" />
    <target dev="vdb" bus="virtio" />
</disk>
```

...to the `<devices>` section?

Many thanks just for reading to end if you managed it.

Answer (score 0):

I use libvirt and pass block devices to VMs. That results in `qemu` parameters like these:

```
-drive file=/dev/mapper/storage-profiles,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk4,format=raw,serial=KVM-profiles,cache=writeback
-device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0xc,drive=drive-virtio-disk4,id=virtio-disk4,bootindex=6
```

Comment: `-drive file=/dev/sdc,if=none,format=raw,aio=native,cache=none,id=hd0 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi -device scsi-block,drive=hd0,bus=scsi.0 \`

This got the device passed through, however it required scsi drivers which I then attempted to install from the /media/LocalBackup/virtio-win-drivers-20120712-1.iso red-hat iso and blue screened and trashed my VM. :D

Happy days.